# I cannot open a website that exists

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am getting an error that makes me believe my program is unable to find a website I know exists.  the website is

```
https://www.transfermarkt.com/marco-reus/verletzungen/spieler/35207
```

My code looks like

```
from urllib import request as u_r

def strip_webite():

  with u_r.urlopen("https://www.transfermarkt.com/marco-reus/verletzungen/spieler/35207") as f:
      pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
  strip_webite()
```

And the error I get is

```
  File "database_management.py", line 19, in <module>
    strip_webite()
  File "database_management.py", line 15, in strip_webite
    with u_r.urlopen("https://www.transfermarkt.com/marco-reus/verletzungen/spieler/35207") as f:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Comment: The error is coming from the call to `urlopen`;  this has nothing to do with BeautifulSoup.

Comment: thought that may be the case, but wasnt 100% sure.  any idea why i cant open it?

Comment: Sorry, it's a mystery to me as well.

Comment: The web server can return whatever response code it wants. Especially to deter web scrapers, which the site probably explicitly says is against its terms of service

Comment: Try adding a header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Transfermarkt is blocking requests from bots with the default `User-Agent` string sent by Python's `urllib` library, though it doesn't mention anything about that in its [robots](https://www.transfermarkt.com/robots.txt).

This seems to imply they don't mind us scraping them, but they'd prefer we announce who we are.

To do so with urllib, do the following:

```
from urllib import request as u_r

def strip_webite():

  request = u_r.Request("https://www.transfermarkt.com/marco-reus/verletzungen/spieler/35207")
  request.add_header('User-Agent', 'my-cool-app')
  with u_r.urlopen(request) as f:
      pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
  strip_webite()
```

Comment: So, this the descriptive headers you have used. How about this: `headers={'User-Agent': 'not found 404'}`. It will fetch you the same response. When you deal with the rain, you need to care for the mud as well.

Comment: I don't know what his application is doing, so I can't come up with a descriptive UA string.  I put an obvious placeholder which is unlikely to be present in the wild, so, if he does use it, the webmaster can block him if he wants.

Comment: `urllib` broadcasts a user-agent header (it's 'Python-urllib/version'), so the site bropably blocks `urllib`'s default user-agent. Still, this answer solves the problem, so +1